# Access to the propety of an entity from another

Tags: symfony

I am developing on symfony2.8, I have 3 entities: "Candidature", "OffreStage" and "Entreprise",
The "OffreStage" is an intermediate entity between the two other entities, and in my controller I want to display the list of "Candidature" for the current "Entreprise",
Voilà mon controller:

```
 public function listeCandAction(){

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    $user_id = $user->getId();

    $query =$em->createQuery('SELECT u FROM Gestion\StageBundle\Entity\Candidature u WHERE u.valide=0 AND u.offreStage.entreprise =$user_id ' );
    $listcand=$query->getResult();


     return $this->render("StageBundle:Candidature:liste_candidature.html.twig",array('listcand'=>$listcand));
}
```

My problem is in :

```
u.offreStage.entreprise =$user_id
```

Can you help me please ? thank You All

Comment: I recommend reading about SQL and Joins first. How to achieve it with Doctrine is mentioned [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins)

Comment: Thanks a lot @LBA